# I want to put a background image in a blade from a Laravel project

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, laravel-blade

I just started to use laravel for a project and i want for my homepage a full background image.I tried the normal css html method but it is not working.Here is my code
home.blade.php:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title> AgroHelp Login</title>
  <link href="{{asset('css/home.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<div class='view_parent_image1'>

    </div>
<p style ="text-align:center;">This is full screen</p>


</body>
```

and this is home.css

```
.view_parent_image1{
   background-image: url('../resources/Image/JD.jpg');
   background-size: cover;
}
```

my image is in resources/Image/JD.jpg;
and home.css is in public/css/home.css;

Comment: You need to give full path of image

Comment: add some content in view_parent_image1 div...

Comment: Itried the full path but still not working.And i tried adding some content in div.Still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Laravel, your CSS file can't access to /resources directory.

You should move this image from resources to public dir. Have a look on [Laravel Mix - Copyin Files](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mix#copying-files-and-directories) to manage your project's public assets.

I Thinks that should work for you.

Answer (score 2):

Check this out:

```
.view_parent_image1{
   background: url('{{asset('uploads/'.$ourService->imageOne)}}');
   background-size: cover;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try some thing like this

```
body {
   background-image: url('../resources/Image/JD.jpg');
   background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

place your image into **public/uploads** path and use this

```
.view_parent_image1{
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url({{ URL::asset('uploads/background_image.png') }}) no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
```